# Get all Facebook Statuses

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to come up with an app that's something like Archivebook where I can get all statuses a user posted. So far I have this code, but it's limited to 100.

```
    $status = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' =>"SELECT message FROM status WHERE uid = me()"));
$i = 1;

foreach ($status as $statuses) {        
    echo $i. ". " .$statuses['message'] ."</br>"; //display status
    $i++;   //append
```

I first call the API through a query, then output the array and number it. All permissions are properly set.

Comment: Your code works for me... what permissions are you asking for?

Comment: More detail on this issue here - apparently it has been fixed: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/323482411070909/

Comment: The code works, but I can only get 100 statuses. I can LIMIT 100 and OFFSET 100 but I can't call it twice and get 200. I know that Archive Book has a way around this, I am not sure what it is tho. Any fix for this?